# Javascript: Disable select options in Select 2 based on Select 1

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

My program has a two select fields with the same options.

```
<select id="startDate">
    <option value="2014-07-11">July. 11th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-07-25">July. 25th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-08-08">August. 8th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-08-22">August. 22th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-09-05">September. 5th, 2014</option>
</select>


<select id="endDate">
    <option value="2014-07-11">July. 11th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-07-25">July. 25th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-08-08">August. 8th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-08-22">August. 22th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-09-05">September. 5th, 2014</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is on change of the startDate based on the selection, disable all options before that date in endDate. So for example, if August. 8th, 2014 is selected in startDate, disable the first 2 options in endDate. So July 11th and July 15th should be disabled in endDate.

How could I go about achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to bind `onchange` event. Then you loop over second select options and disabled/enable them based on the selected index in the first select. Note, that you don't even have to compare option values because both selectboxes has the same set of options:

```js
document.querySelector('#startDate').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var endDate = document.querySelector('#endDate');
    for (var i = 0; i < endDate.options.length; i++) {
        endDate.options[i].disabled = i < this.selectedIndex;
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="startDate">
    <option value="2014-07-11">July. 11th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-07-25">July. 25th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-08-08">August. 8th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-08-22">August. 22th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-09-05">September. 5th, 2014</option>
</select>

<select id="endDate">
    <option value="2014-07-11">July. 11th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-07-25">July. 25th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-08-08">August. 8th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-08-22">August. 22th, 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-09-05">September. 5th, 2014</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: One last thing. After a selection has been made on the first Select, I would like to make the second Select selectedIndex the next enabled option. Would I do something like endDate.selectedIndex[i+1] outside the for statement?

Comment: `selectedIndex` is already next enabled option in the second select. Or I don't understand you?

Answer (score 0):

```
var sl1 = document.getElementById('startDate');
var sl2 = document.getElementById('endDate');

sl1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var opts = sl2.childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
        if(opts[i].value < sl1.value)
            opts[i].disabled = true;
    }
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/v25zwbez/)